# ASP.Net MVC: facebook logged in user's email is not coming to my site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

i am using asp.net mvc 5. when i log in to facebook then i am redirect to page called **ExternalLoginCallback** there a textbox comes where i ask to put user email but i believe i should get fb logged in user's email automatically but nothing such coming. here is screen shot.

[image]

i just add these line of code for facebook auth.

```
    app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
    {
        AppId = "222222222222222222",
        AppSecret = "sssssssssssssssssss",
        Scope = { "email" },
        Fields = { "name", "email" }
    });
```

anyone can tell me what kind of mistake i have made for which email is not coming in my case.

looking for a help. thanks

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/16/get-more-information-from-social-providers-used-in-the-vs-2013-project-templates/